# pyinstall compiler script for other server can not run it

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I have a python script, and I use pyinstall to make a onefile

but when I use this file to other server,has some problem

```
[root@ops-pdc-02 tmp]# ./linux_server_script 
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/build/linux_server_script/out00-PYZ.pyz/hashlib", line 147, in <module>
  File "/tmp/build/linux_server_script/out00-PYZ.pyz/hashlib", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/build/linux_server_script/out00-PYZ.pyz/hashlib", line 147, in <module>
  File "/tmp/build/linux_server_script/out00-PYZ.pyz/hashlib", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/build/linux_server_script/out00-PYZ.pyz/hashlib", line 147, in <module>
  File "/tmp/build/linux_server_script/out00-PYZ.pyz/hashlib", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/build/linux_server_script/out00-PYZ.pyz/hashlib", line 147, in <module>
  File "/tmp/build/linux_server_script/out00-PYZ.pyz/hashlib", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
```

and my server has openssl lib and I use python shell look hashlib modules,that is correct。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's openssl badlly,so download ssl CERTIFICATE see

http://drops.cnmoker.org/archives/403.html

老版本的openssl会有一个坑，由于证书太老，导致openssl CURL python pip都错误

解决办法，下载一个新的CA证书，替换掉老的/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

https://labs.bitpay.com/t/how-to-update-the-root-ca-cert-bundle-on-your-webserver-if-you-are-getting-curl-ssl-errors/315

and maybe attention GLIBC version